# synchronize folders which are located on different servers

Tags: ssh, cronjob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synchronise system changes on two computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/178944/synchronise-system-changes-on-two-computers)

how to synchronize two folders which are located on different servers. I need that if someone put any data on folder A then it will automatically copy in folder B. Folder A is in German Server and folder B is in Indian Server. I have Admin Access on Indian Server and user access on German Server. Both file server are on Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 0):

Just schedule a local [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), over ssh job, to run every few min's, it's secure and reliable e.g.

```
2,12,22,32,42,52 * * * * /usr/bin/rsync -optlgrz --delete-after --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync --force /local_directory/  user@remoteHost:/dest_directory  2>&1  >>/var/log/rsync_directory.log
```